# Questioner's liability for receiving a wrong psak

Tags: halacha, sin, korban, posek-psak-decisor-ruling

If someone asked a competent Rav a shaila, and the Rav was wrong, is the "questioner" liable? For example, if someone asked a Rav if one is permitted to water his plants on Shabbat and the Rav mistakenly answered that it is permitted. Would the asker be considered "Shogeg" and be obligated in a Chatat? or is it "Ones" and he is not liable?

Comment: When there was a Sanhedrin and korbanot, whether the individuals had to bring personal korbanot or the Sanhedrin had to bring a korban for the community depended largely on whether the majority of the community followed their incorrect ruling (among other things)

Comment: @Daniel Are you saying the individual will need to bring a korban if the Sanhedrin does not? And if it's not a Sanhedrin giving the ruling?

Comment: @Moses613 No I'm not saying that. Just pointing out that there is a similar case which is discussed. It is possible that the parallels don't extend to asking a rabbi a question nowadays. To answer your other question, if less than half of the relevant community followed the Sanhedrin's incorrect ruling, it was the responsibility of the individuals to bring a sacrifice, not the Sanhedrin.