# "Where's the court's power to assess?" Who cares?

Tags: beit-din-court, maseches-kesubos

The *mishna*, [*K'subos* 11:5](https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%99%D7%90_%D7%94), quotes *Raban Shim'on ben Gamliel* as saying that a court's property assessment is effective even when found to be far off the mark. The reason he gives is "otherwise, where's the court's power?". I fail to understand this. Why are we interested in boosting the power of the court in this regard? I can understand we want the court's decisions to have teeth, but that's in regard to decisions of guilt, innocence, liability, lack of liability, etc. If the court is not believed in such decisions, people will adjudge cases privately and anarchy will reign. But if the court is not believed in assessments, people will assess property privately and… so what? We don't mind people's assessing property privately, do we? Why do we need to enact a safeguard for the court's power?

Comment: See my answer to https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/104379/15579 This is similar to Kohen's power of Erchin - does he REVEAL the value or SET that value, same here. If we follow the second approach, the Beis Din sets the value and that's its power.

Comment: note that commentators say that there is not machloket between Tana Kama and Rashbag for this point.

Comment: My opinion: is a din of Hefker Bet din Hefker, זה מדין הפקר בית דין הפקר למרות שלא מינו אותו ב"ד, בכ"ז העובדא שקיבלו אותו עליהם משרה בו את הכוח הזה בטועה בדבר משנה, ונראה כסעד לסברא, שיש להעריך שהרגישו שטעה ובכ"ז סמכו עליו, או שיכלו לבדוק אותו ולא בדקו וזה מחזק את הודאות שסומכים עליו אבל בטועה בשיקול הדעת, מן הסתם לא היו מסוגלים לבדוק ולא מוכח כ"כ שסמכו עליו.

Comment: See Bechorot 4.4 in Bartenura and TYT and Sanhedrin 3.1 in Bartenura.